# NodeJs npm requestretry package Not Work on AWS Lambda Nodejs8.10

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Here is my nodejs8.10 test code:

```
var request = require('requestretry');
const testRequest = async() =>{
  request({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    json: true,        
    maxAttempts: 5,   // (default) try 5 times
    retryDelay: 5000,  // (default) wait for 5s before trying again
    retryStrategy: request.RetryStrategies.HTTPOrNetworkError 
  }, function(err, response, body){       
    if (response) {
        console.log('The number of request attempts: ' + response.attempts);
        console.log(body);
    }else{
         console.log('error: ', err);
    }
  });
}


testRequest(); // for local implementation

exports.handler = async (event) => {    
  let x = await testRequest();
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Test Lambda!'),
  };

  return response;
};
```

vs. nodejs6.10 test code:

```
var request = require('requestretry');

function testRequest () {
  request({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    json: true,
    // The below parameters are specific to request-retry
    maxAttempts: 5,   // (default) try 5 times
    retryDelay: 5000,  // (default) wait for 5s before trying again
    retryStrategy: request.RetryStrategies.HTTPOrNetworkError // (default) retry on 5xx or network errors
  }, function(err, response, body){
    // this callback will only be called when the request succeeded or after maxAttempts or on error
    if (response) {            
        console.log(body);
    }
  });
}

 testRequest();

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
     testRequest();
     const response = {
       statusCode: 200,
       body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
     };
    callback(null, response);
 };
```

It won't display the log that related to requestretry package on lambda Nodejs 8.10 and no any error messages. However, it can get the response and logs by running with command `node <filename>` in the local machine after `npm install` with the necessary packages like 'requestretry' and its required packages. If the above file converted into Nodejs6.10 format and it won't have the issue on both aws lambda and local machine.

I need to find out the causing before I convert the codes from nodejs6.10 (callback format)to nodejs8.10 (async format).

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain a bit more about how you reproduce the problem, and what research you have done.

Comment: Are you bundling your `node_modules` folder as part of a .zip upload? How are you getting the npm module somewhere that your function can find it?

Comment: All requestretry package and related packages are in node_modules and bundled into .zip and uploaded to aws lambda. If the above codes converted into node6.10 format and it won't have the issue for the lambda. It's only happened in the aws node8.10 lambda version.